# Draw random number from text file

Tags: ruby

So i have this code putting some numbers into a text file.

```
outFile = File.new("Demo.txt", "a+")
outFile.puts (1..5).map{ '%05d' % rand(00000..99999) }
outFile.close
puts File.read("Demo.txt")
```

And I would like to know if I can draw out one of the random numbers that have been created.

Comment: Just read all numbers from the file into an array and then select random element of that array.

Comment: Could you paste the code you tried to solve it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show any solution attempts.

Comment: You could easily store your array of strings in a variable before you go putting it in the the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do as below :

```
File.open("Demo.txt", "a+") do |file|
  file.puts (1..5).map{ '%05d' % rand(00000..99999) }
end
# give you any random number from the file
puts File.readlines("Demo.txt").map(&:strip).sample
```

[`IO::readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines) will give you all the numbers you put inside the file `"Demo.txt"`, as an `Array`. Now [`Array#sample`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-sample), will *choose a random element*.

Why I used [`IO::open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-open) ? Read the below for the same :

> With no associated block, `IO.open` is a synonym for `::new`. *If the optional code block is given, it will be passed io as an argument, and the IO object will automatically be **closed when the block terminates**.* In this instance, `::open` returns the value of the block.

Comment: Thanks! that will help me alot :)